# WooCommerce triggers function when order completed, however Python script called within it does not execute

Tags: php, python, wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to Wordpress/Woocommerce and am trying to fire a python script when an order has been completed. I created the following plugin:

```
<?php

    /**
     * Plugin Name: Run Python Script on Order Completion
     * Plugin URI: http://www.mindspan.net
     * Description: Fires a Python script which queries the database
     * Version: 1.0
     * Author: Ray Richards
     * Author URI: http://www.mindspan.net
     */

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    function  logIt( $order_id ) {
        error_log( "Order complete for order $order_id", 0 );
        $command = escapeshellcmd('/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mindspan/getValues.py');
        shell_exec($command);
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'logIt', 10, 1 );

    ?>
```

When an order is completed, the function definitely executes as I get, for example, "Order complete for order 8679" in the PHP error log -- with no other errors indicated; however, the Python script referenced in the function is not run. Here is the Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import mysql.connector

textFile = open("testing.txt", "w+")
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="myHost",
  user="myUser",
  passwd="myPassword",
  database="myDatabase"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT guid  FROM wpv2_posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_order' AND post_status = 'wc-completed' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for result, in myresult:
   print(result)
   textFile.write("%s \n" % result)
textFile.close()
```

The folder and files are owned by the www-data user (am on Debian stretch hosted on Google's cloud platform) and when I su to that user and execute the function from the command line (commenting out the add_action part):

```
sudo su www-data -s /bin/sh
php -r "require 'myFile.php'; logIt(8679);"
```

The Python script executes and the file with the results is created.

I have also tried system() and passthru() and put another error log AFTER the two lines calling the Python script and it outputs that message in the log as well. When I create another test.php file with the following contents:

```
<?php
//$command = escapeshellcmd('/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mindspan/getValues.py');
//shell_exec($command);

passthru('/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mindspan/getValues.py 1 2>&1');
?>
```

and run it from the command line both the commented and uncommented commands work as expected. I have even changed (temporarily) the directory permissions to 777... no dice.

So I would like to understand what is preventing the Python script from being run when it is called from WooCommerce PHP. Any suggestions would be sincerely appreciated!

Comment: Did you check the 'disable_functions' directive in php.ini?

Comment: @magenta Thanks for responding. My disable_functions is as follows: ` disable_functions = pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wifcontinued,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,` Any of these problematic?

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, given I can run the script directly from PHP.

Comment: I have also added www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/bin/python to my sudoers file and tried nohup in my script... all to no avail.

Comment: It is also definitely trying to run the python script because when I put a syntax error in it, it shows in the /var/log/apache2/error.log, so perhaps the issue is writing the output to a file, but I can't see any issues with permissions.

Comment: The script executed from the command shell runs in a different environment from the script run by the HTTP server. In particular, there usually is a php.ini for CLI and a different php.ini for the HTTP server. The environment variables may also be different so running the script from the CLI doesn't mean that the script will run in the HTTP server environment. However, the syntax error in the log means that the environment is probably not the issue.

Comment: I changed the php.ini in the /etc/php/7.0/apache2/ directory... I assume this is the correct place?

Comment: Probably, there are multiple php.ini for the server depending on the version of php you are running. Anyway, the Python syntax error in the log says that php.ini is probably not the issue.

Comment: Instead of writing a file try returning the Python output to PHP.

Comment: open("testing.txt", "w+") - are you sure you have write access to the directory where testing.txt will be created. This directory may be different for script when run from the CLI and when run from the HTTP server. Probably, better to use a fully qualified path. Are you sure you are looking in the right directory?

Comment: Wow. That was it. The script was in the same directory that the plugin was in which had full rights; however, adding the full path to the .py file in the PHP one did the trick. I can't believe this cost me almost 2 days of frustration. Thanks so much.